# what characters are allowed in HTTP header values?

Tags: http, http-headers

After studying [HTTP/1.1 standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), specifically page 31 and related I came to conclusion that any 8-bit octet can be present in HTTP header value. I.e. any character with code from [0,255] range.

And yet HTTP servers I tried refuse to take anything with code > 127 (or most US-ASCII non-printable chars).

Here is dried out excerpt of grammar used in standard:

```
message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value and consisting of
                  either *TEXT or combinations of token, separators, and
                  quoted-string>

CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>
CRLF           = CR LF
LWS            = [CRLF] 1*( SP | HT )
OCTET          = <any 8-bit sequence of data>
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS>

token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@" | "," | ";" | ":" | "\"
               | <"> | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "=" | "{" | "}" | SP | HT

quoted-string  = ( <"> *(qdtext | quoted-pair ) <"> )
qdtext         = <any TEXT except <">>
quoted-pair    = "\" CHAR
```

As you can see `field-content` can be a `quoted-string`, which is an enquoted sequence of `TEXT` (i.e. any 8-bit octet with exception of `"` and values from `[0-8, 11-12, 14-31, 127]` range) or `quoted-pair` (`\` followed by any value from `[0, 127]` range). I.e. any 8-bit char sequence can be passed by en-quoting it and prefixing special symbols with `\`).

(Note that standard doesn't treat `NUL(0x00)` char in any special way)

But, obviously either all servers I tried are not conforming or standard has changed since 1999 or I can't read it properly.

So... which characters are allowed in HTTP header values and why?

P.S. Reason behind all of this: I am looking for a way to pass utf-8-encoded sequence in HTTP header value (without additional encoding, if possible).

Comment: Looks like no one really took this part of standard seriously. I ended up simply [url-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) header values.

Comment: Note that `separators` in `field-names` need to be encoded too. Also, if you use WinHTTP -- you'll have to encode single quote symbol in `field-name`, or request will fail.

Comment: Hint: RFC 2616 is entirely irrelevant. Please see RFC 7230.

Comment: @JulianReschke I didn't know about RFC 7230. Is it an official HTTP/1.1 standard? (asking because greenbytes link points to a document marked "PROPOSED STANDARD")

Comment: RFC 7230 did not rewrite RFC 2616 - it clarifed it _thankfully_. [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2] (§3.2) uses the token VCHAR to specify the allowable field-contents; VCHAR is defined in [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-1.2] (§1.2) as any visible USASCII character. This clarified token removes the need to spend time culling out non-visible characters like RFC 2616 did, but **does not expand** the 1999/1982 definition to include 128-255. The OP's question is "which characters are allowed in HTTP header values and why". I have answered that, with references.

Comment: @C.M. - yes, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2616

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header)

Comment: @miken32 No, not really -- I don't care how HTTP header is encoded, my question was about characters allowed in certain part of HTTP header.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) is obsolete, the relevant part has been replaced by [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-9).

> The NUL octet is no longer allowed in comment and quoted-string text,
> and handling of backslash-escaping in them has been clarified. The
> quoted-pair rule no longer allows escaping control characters other
> than HTAB. *Non-US-ASCII content in header fields and the reason phrase
> has been obsoleted and made opaque (the TEXT rule was removed).*
> (Section 3.2.6)

In essence, RFC 2616 defaulted to [ISO-8859-1](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231211215/http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC2/WG3/docs/n411.pdf), and this was both insufficient and not interoperable anyway. Thus, RFC 7230 has deprecated non-ASCII octets in field values. The recommendation is to use an escaping mechanism on top of that (such as defined in [RFC 8187](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8187), or plain URI-percent-encoding).

Comment: Is RFC 2616 obsolete? Yes. Does that answer the OP's question of "which characters are allowed in HTTP header values and why"? No.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters are deprecated. You can send them, but there's no guarantee that the recipient will do what you expect it to.

That's what the spec says, and that's the answer :-)

Comment: @JulianReschke I finally got around to read RFC 7230. I don't see any "obsoletion" of non-US-ASCII content in [p3.2.6](https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.2.6) -- it seems it allows any `0x80-0xFF` char in `quoted-string`. `0x00-0x7F` range got decimated though. I.e. according to this standard you can pass utf-8 data in header value as long as you escape "forbidden" part of `0x00-0x7F` range. Am I wrong?

Comment: `field-name` can contain `'` too... I guess this special case will have to remain in my code if I care about MS webservers.

Comment: "As a convention, ABNF rule names prefixed with "obs-" denote "obsolete" grammar rules that appear for historical reasons." - https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.1.2.p.3

Comment: @JulianReschke Ah, I see... So, using `0x80-0xFF` range is OK now (but disencouraged), but will be removed in future HTTP versions? I.e. back to my original question -- with HTTP/1.1 it should be ok to pass utf-8 encoded data as header values (double-enquoted with double quotes and backslash escaped) as long as it doesn't contain forbidden values from `0x00-0x7F` range?

Comment: @JulianReschke ... i.e. what meaning standard's authors put into "obsolete"?

Comment: Note that RFC 9110, which obsoletes RFC 7230, has an updated discussion on this which I found helpful: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-5.5

Answer (score 17):

For all the people like me who came here for the title ***"what characters are allowed in HTTP header values?"***

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.~
!#$&'()*+,/:;=?@[]
%20,%21,%22,%23,%24,%25,%26,%27,%28,%29,%2A,%2B,%2C,%2F,%3A,%3B,%3D,%3F,%40,%5B,%5D
```

from [@C.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6427477/c-m)'s comment mentioning [wikipedia's url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding)

- RFC 3986 section 2.2 Reserved Characters (January 2005)

`!#$&'()*+,/:;=?@[]`

- RFC 3986 section 2.3 Unreserved Characters (January 2005)

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.~`

- Reserved characters after percent-encoding ( ␣ == " " )

| ␣ | ! | " | # | $ | % | & | ' | ( | ) | * | + | , | / | : | ; | = | ? | @ | [ | ] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| %20 | %21 | %22 | %23 | %24 | %25 | %26 | %27 | %28 | %29 | %2A | %2B | %2C | %2F | %3A | %3B | %3D | %3F | %40 | %5B | %5D |

- and a helpful json for our python code:

```py
[
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", ".", "~"],
    ["!", "#", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "/", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@", "[", "]"],
    {" ": "%20", "!": "%21", "\"": "%22", "#": "%23", "$": "%24", "%": "%25", "&": "%26", "'": "%27", "(": "%28", ")": "%29", "*": "%2A", "+": "%2B", ",": "%2C", "/": "%2F", ":": "%3A", ";": "%3B", "=": "%3D", "?": "%3F", "@": "%40", "[": "%5B", "]": "%5D"}
]
```

I believe [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138818/19907524) answered the OP's "why"

Answer (score -3):

It looks as if there is an error in the [HTTP/1.1 specs](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). As you pointed out, §4.2 describes the field content as OCTET:

> field-content  = the OCTETs making up the field-value

And OCTET is defined in §2.2 as:

> OCTET          = any 8-bit sequence of data

These lines are the basis of your conclusion that octets > 127 should be allowed, and certainly I see how you have drawn that conclusion. The mention of OCTET in §4.2 is the misleading error; it should be CHAR.

If you read §4.2 (Message Headers) from the beginning, you will note the following guidance:

> HTTP header fields...follow the same generic format as that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822

If we do as instructed and go to [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt), specifically §3.1.2 (Structure of header fields), we learn the following:

> The  field-name must be composed of printable ASCII characters
>   (i.e., characters that  have  values  between  33.  and  126.,
>   decimal, except colon).  **The field-body may be composed of any
>   ASCII characters**, except CR or LF.

So while HTTP/1.1 was written in 1999, they used a definition from 1982 to describe the field contents. In 1982, characters 0-127 were called "ASCII" and 128-255 were called "Extended ASCII". Now, in this answer I am not going to get involved in [the food fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) that gets evoked when using the term "Extended ASCII". **I will simply point you to §3.3 of RFC 822 for the definition of what was *then* considered "any ASCII character"**:

> CHAR = any ASCII character ( Octal: 0-177,  Decimal: 0.-127.)

And so there you have it - the smoking gun. "ASCII" stopped at 127 in 1982. The written paragraph portion of RFC 2616 §4.2 points you in the right direction, and the unfortunate later misuse of the token OCTET in that same section led you down this rabbit hole.

Comment: That interpretation is wrong, see specifically <https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.2.2.p.4>.

Comment: I agree with Geek Stocks that there is a deficiency or misrepresentation in RFC 2616. But @JulianReschke seems to be correct too -- it seems there was a conscious attempt to include non-ASCII characters. I guess standard was written by multiple people with different views on the subject matter?

Comment: @JulianReschke It is **not** wrong. (1) In 1999 RFC 2616 defined the contents as decimal 0...127 and culling out the non-visible in that range — that is indisputable and I have shown that. (2) RFC 7230 **did not expand** the allowable characters to include non-visible ASCII > 127. Your link is just a copy of RFC 2616.

Comment: @GeekStocks - you are drawing an incorrect conclusion. RFC 2616 indeed allowed non-ASCII characters. RFC 7230 has deprecated them due to the reasons I mentioned (and I should know, I'm one of the authors).

"follows the format" is an explanation where the format originated from; it's not a normative reference.

Comment: @JulianReschke - this is truly getting laughable. Let's see if I can put a fork in this. The OP states "...servers I tried refuse to take anything with code > 127". Your own link to RFC 2616 §2.2 shows **why** the OP can't send 128...255. It states _The US-ASCII coded character set is defined by ANSI X3.4-1986 [footnote 21]_ . Go to footnote 21. It is a citation to **7-bit American Standard Code**. Now, tell me how you get a number >127 with only 7 bits? _(drops the mic)_  ;-p

Comment: In RFC 2616, the ABNF for "TEXT" is "<any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS>". OCTET is defined as "<any 8-bit sequence of data>". In addition to that, RFC 2616 very clearly says: "Words of \*TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO-8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047 [14]." - so characters from ISO-8859-1 (which is a super set of US-ASCII) *can* be used in TEXT. I think that's pretty clear.

The reference to US-ASCII applies to the ABNF rules that say "US-ASCII", not to OCTET.

Comment: I just want to know what the valid chars are in an HTTP Header value.  Untangling a moving target of self-referential ABNF docs is not productive. We need a working reference implementation with unit tests to clarify edge cases to fix this hell.

Why there are so many different ways of handling meta data?  Is this to create job security for web developers or create new security attack surfaces for security companies to fix?