# Firebase custom domain not getting requested headers

Tags: firebase, http, http-headers, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Google Cloud Function (GCF) that check if a requested header is added then continue working. 
The GCF is working on:
`https://us-central1-*******.cloudfunctions.net/NowShowing`
normally, but if we add a custom domain 
`https://******.firebaseapp.com` and run the Cloud Function 
`https://******.firebaseapp.com/NowShowing`, the Cloud Function is not getting the requested header and it is not working

```
exports.NowShowing = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
cors(request, response, () => {
    if (request.header('_api_key') == "whatever") {
     // code
    }
 })
})
```

any idea how to be fixed

Comment: fixed.... headers with "_" character not accepted

Comment: Sounds like a good self-answer @allo! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see you already found the answer to your own question. That's true, headers with "_" character are not accepted.

You can see more information here:

> [what characters are allowed in HTTP header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687379/what-characters-are-allowed-in-http-header-values)