# Request header encoding changed with empty body

Tags: java, postman

facing a weird issue while sending ÷ (division) in request header.
i have a login API which accepts emailId and password. I created a password `Abc!23÷`. Whenever i am trying to login to my application from web i could able to login but when trying to invoke same login API from postman client with empty body `{}` what i am seeing is above password got changed to `Abc!23Ã·`. Because of that my login call is failing. Is postman encoding this ÷ divisional char.I couldn't able to figure out what is going on. Someone could help me here. I am using postman Version 7.33.1 on a mac laptop.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/ABCD/session/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'loginId: Team.Z+9@abc.com' \
--header 'password: Abc!23÷' \
--header 'orgId: abcd' \
--data-raw '{}'
```

Comment: Coukd you please post your complete request from Postman, eg. export to curl. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann i have updated my question with curl request.

Comment: It indeed looks like the `÷` is causing the trouble. Not an expert on the field, but it seems that depending on the http version there are different encodings being used (ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8). Didn't find a solution for your issue, but these links should help you out: [what characters are allowed in HTTP header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687379/what-characters-are-allowed-in-http-header-values), [UTF-8 in HTTP Headers](https://dzone.com/articles/utf-8-in-http-headers).