# ñ character in ASP.NET Core 3.1 http header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 web server and I'm receiving post requests like this:

```
[HttpPost("/api/loginweb")]
        public IActionResult loginWeb([FromHeader(Name = "usuario")] String usuario, [FromHeader(Name = "pass")] String pass)
        {
```

The problem I have is sending the ñ character on a header:

[image]

But, when I receive it I get:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `right-click` barñfoo in postman, choose **EncodeURlComponent** option, and then when the data of `usuario` is received, use **HttpUtility.UrlDecode()** method to get the string containing special characters.

```
 [HttpPost("/api/loginweb")]
        public IActionResult loginWeb([FromHeader(Name = "usuario")] string usuario, [FromHeader(Name = "pass")] string pass)
        {
            usuario = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(usuario);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is the process to test:

[image]

### Update

I have found a thread which explains the reason of this phenomena.
You can have a look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138818/12884742)

Comment: Well, yes, I finnally encoded it on the client side as in my case it depends on me, but I didn't want to do that, I just want to be able to make the API understand the encoding, like in any other languges and frameworks... I see your answer like a workaround. Maybe it is imposible and your approach is the best one...

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí,Sorry, this is the solution I have found so far. If allowed, putting it in the body rather than header and passing it will not cause this issue.

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí ,I have updated my reply, you could refer it, if it helped you ,please accept as the answer.