# The HTTP response header [Saved-url] with value has been removed from the response because it is invalid

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I see the following warning in the Tomcat logs:

```
WARN 1208786 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : The HTTP response header [Saved-url] with value [https://example.com/jobs/1234/СЃС†РµРЅР°СЂРёСЃС‚-РґР»СЏ-youtube-РєР°РЅР°Р»Сѓ] has been removed from the response because it is invalid

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [СЃ] at code point [1,089] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.toBytesSimple(MessageBytes.java:286) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.toBytes(MessageBytes.java:259) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.write(Http11OutputBuffer.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.sendHeader(Http11OutputBuffer.java:368) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1051) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:376) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:444) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:287) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:413) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:370) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
```

Should I be concerned about this? If so, how can I properly configure Spring Boot/Tomcat to address this issue?

Comment: That URL contains characters outside the ascii range is not "percent" encoded that's why is marked invalid but the main concern could be that the application is returning a custom `saved-url` response header with invalid content. Where that header comes from? Probably nothing to do with tomcat itself

Comment: I have NGINX in front of Tomcat

Comment: and then my app

Answer (score 1):

It is because Tomcat as a HTTP compliance server is trying to enforce the HTTP header rule that any characters in the HTTP header and value should be within the ASCII codes from [0 to 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687379/what-characters-are-allowed-in-http-header-values). But now your application are sending out a response whose values in the `Saved-url` header violate this rule and hence tomcat remove it.

The client can still receive the response body and the expected status code .It just cannot find any `Saved-url` response header.

And briefly check with the related part of tomcat source codes and don't think there are ways to configure such checking.